# From scanner to arraylist

Tags: java

I would like to create arraylist from scanner input. It's motorcycles rental system. Help please :) I'm absolute beginner :D

I'm trying to create table like this:
(date, date, name, licenceID)

1. 2016-08-09, 2016-08-20, Mr Smith, 1234567
2. 2016-08-05, 2016-08-06, Mr Jackson, 6435434

This is my code:

```
public class Launcher{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Launcher> reservationlist = new ArrayList<>();
        reservationlist.add(2016-08-09, 2016-08-20, Mr Smith, 1234567; // there is an error

        Helper.welcomeMessage();
        char choice, ignore;

        for (;;) {
            do {
                Helper.showMenu();

                choice = (char) System.in.read();
                do {
                    ignore = (char) System.in.read();
                } while (ignore != '\n');
            } while (choice < '1' | choice > '5' & choice != 'q');
            if (choice == 'q') {
                break;
            }

           Orders order = new Orders();

            switch (choice) {
                case '1': // Get information about company
                    Helper.aboutUs();
                    break;
                case '2': // List of our motorcycles (enum)
                    System.out.println("Price per 1 day:  PREMIUM 500, GOLD 500, BASIC 500");
                    for (Prices pricelist : Prices.values())
                        System.out.printf("%s\t%s\n", pricelist.getTitle(), pricelist);
                    break;
                case '3': // Make a reservation
                    Scanner hp = new Scanner(System.in);
                    Orders reservation = new Orders();

                    System.out.println("Type initial date:");
                    reservation.initialDate = hp.next();

                    System.out.println("Type final date:");
                    reservation.finalDate = hp.next();

                    System.out.println("Type your first name and last name:");
                    reservation.name = hp.next();

                    System.out.print("Type your driving licence ID:");
                    reservation.drivingLicenceID = hp.next();

                    System.out.println("\n\n Reservation completed " + reservation.name + "\n Thanks for your reservation\n");
                    break;

                    reservationlist.add(reservation.initialDate, reservation.finalDate, reservation.name, reservation.drivingLicenceID));  // there is an error

                case '4': // Check availability of motorcycles
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                case '5': // Contact with us
                    Helper.contact();
                    break;
            }


public class Orders {

        String initialDate;
        String finalDate;
        String name;
        String drivingLicenceID;

    public Orders(String initialDate, String finalDate, String name, String drivingLicenceID) {
        this.initialDate = initialDate;
        this.finalDate = finalDate;
        this.name = name;
        this.drivingLicenceID = drivingLicenceID;
    }

    public Orders() {}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Orders{" +
                "initialDate='" + initialDate + '\'' +
                ", finalDate='" + finalDate + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", drivingLicenceID=" + drivingLicenceID +
                '}';
    }

    public void setInitialDate(String initialDate) {
        this.initialDate = initialDate;
    }
    public void setFinalDate(String finalDate) {
        this.finalDate = finalDate;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setDrivingLicenceID(String drivingLicenceID) {
        this.drivingLicenceID = drivingLicenceID;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's your code, but you forgot the question.

Comment: `reservationlist.add(2016-08-09, 2016-08-20, Mr Smith, 1234567;` What is the expected outcome of this line? First, it is missing a necessary`)`. Second, the method `add` is expecting you to provide a `Launcher`.

Comment: There are several major errors when you're loading data into reservation list. First of all, why are you declaring it of type launcher? Second of all, you're inserting different types into the same arraylist (in Java, arraylists can only have one type of objects stored in them). Third of all, none of the variables you're trying to insert are properly written (i.e. there's no double quotes around the string and the date is written like an expression). I highly recommend you start with a smaller program, and work your way up.

Comment: Also, don't ignore errors. Fix them, and then move on to the next part.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that what you try to achieve is rather this:

```
List<Orders> reservationlist = new ArrayList<>();
reservationlist.add(new Orders("2016-08-09", "2016-08-20", "Mr Smith", "1234567"));
```

Instead of

```
ArrayList<Launcher> reservationlist = new ArrayList<>();
reservationlist.add(2016-08-09, 2016-08-20, Mr Smith, 1234567; // there is an error
```

And this:

```
reservationlist.add(reservation);
```

Instead of

```
reservationlist.add(
    reservation.initialDate, reservation.finalDate, reservation.name, 
    reservation.drivingLicenceID)
);  // there is an error
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857009/5012644) explained, another obvious syntax error lies within the following:

```
while (choice < '1' | choice > '5' & choice != 'q');
```

You've implemented your [conditional operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) incorrectly. A conditional `OR` syntax is `||` while the syntax for `AND` is `&&`.

Also, do read ['How do I ask a good question?'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).